# What does it mean when a patent has a status of "grant"?

Tags: patentability

US 5333765 shows a status of "grant" on Google. However, in the PAIR database, the status "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" is shown for this patent number.

Does this mean the patent is valid or expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the word "Grant" not "Gant". In the Google Patents listing for [US5333765A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5333765A/en?oq=US5333765A), its status is listed as "Grant" which means a patent was awarded. Checking in the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) indeed indicates that the patent's status is: "Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362" as of 08-30-2006. Nowhere in Pair for this patent did I see the phrase "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action". I'm worried you looked up the wrong document. Pair searching is extremely picky. In this case you need to select "Patent Number" and type "5333765" in the search box.

After a patent is granted, fees are required periodically to keep it in force. The owner of this patent missed one of the later fee payments so the patent expired. While it might have been possible to resurrect the patent if the missed payment was inadvertent, the patent would have expired in any case 20 years from its priority date of August 22, 1991. Thus this patent has expired and can not be infringed upon.